# Using large datasets for training in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api

I created a training dataset using polygons outside of GEE and I want to use them now in GEE for a supervised classification in Sentinel-2 images.
However when I try to create training points from it as seen below I get `Computation timed out.` or `User memory limit exceeded`. I already reduced the amount of polygons but I still get this error. Is there anything I can due without having to reduce even more the polygons I am using? I've tried using `tileScale`but the same happens.

I understand that the user has a limit of 100MB, and so the amount of data we can feed depends on the data types and how the column values are generated. But is there anyway I can know how much data fills those 100MB?

```py
  train_points = image_classification.select(bands).sampleRegions(**{
    'collection': samples,
    'properties': ['class'],
    'scale': 10,
  }).randomColumn('random')
```

Comment: Maybe post an entire working example